# Git no me funciona el .gitignore

Tags: git, github, gitignore

Buenas tengo un repositorio **git** con este `.gitignore`

```
.DS_Store
node_modules/
dist/
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
assets/img/file

# Editor directories and files
.idea
*.suo
*.ntvs*
*.njsproj
*.sln

#Archivos de eclipse
.project
.buildpath
.settings/*

application/cache/*
!application/cache/index.html
/vendor/
application/logs/*
!application/logs/index.html

!application/*/.htaccess

composer.lock

user_guide_src/build/*
user_guide_src/cilexer/build/*
user_guide_src/cilexer/dist/*
user_guide_src/cilexer/pycilexer.egg-info/*


# IDE Files
#-------------------------
/nbproject/
.idea/*
```

Todo funcionaba bien hasta que le quite algunas carpetas ignoradas para poder hacer `pull` en el servidor de calidad pero al volver al desarrollo le agregue de nuevo las carpetas a ignorar y no me la toma sigue subiéndolas al **git**

no tengo ni idea porque no las ignora las carpetas que des ignore fueron:

`dist/` y `/vendor/` pero ahora las sigue tomando aunque las tenga en el `.gitignore`

Hay algun comando que tenga que ejecutar tras hacer un cambio en el `.gitignore`?

Espero hacerme entender de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 7):

Encontré la solución este comando me funciono a la perfección ya me ignora los archivos como antes

### Importante hacer respaldo antes de ejecutar el comando para no perder los cambios (commit)

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "fixed untracked files"
```

Lo encontré en nuestra misma comunidad espero les ayude

### Fuente

[Solución en stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-is-not-working)

Comment: Creo que seria bueno notar que tienes que darle commit a los cambios actuales o sino los perderas.